# How to get the count of Open workorders for a date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

The workorder table shows only the current status of a particular workorder, the wostatus table has the history of the workorder whenever a change happens.. Any workorder that is not in a "close" or "complete" status is considered "Open".

so, I am trying to find out how many workorders were in open status on a particular date, e.g 7-Jul-2016, likewise, the count of open workorders on a given range for each priority. Please check the sample output. thank you and any help is much appreciated ...

**TABLE : WorKOrder**

```
 WoNum,     Priority,   UserID,         Status,             OpenDate,   Description,                            StatusDate, Location
 A17047,    12,         AD201685359,    WaitingMaterials,   30-Jun-16,  laptop fan not working,                 2-Jul-15,   HR
 A55198,    12,         AD201658376,    WaitingApproval,    01-Jul-16,  Need help with connecting two monitors, 1-Jul-16,   Finance
 A35508,    4,          AD201621226,    Close,              02-Jul-16,  Upgrade memory to 8GB,                  8-Jul-16,   Media
```

**TABLE : wostatus**

```
Wonum,  Status,             changedate, changedby
A17047, InProgress,         30-Jun-16,  AD201659555
A17047, Approved,           01-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A17047, WaitingMaterials,   02-Jul-15,  AD201659555
A55198, InProgress,         01-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A55198, WaitingApproval,    01-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A35508, InProgress,         02-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A35508, WaitingApproval,    02-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A35508, Approved,           03-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A35508, Complete,           08-Jul-16,  AD201659555
A35508, Close,              08-Jul-16,  AD201659555
```

**Query Output / Want the output to look like this**

```
Date, Total P12 Open WorkOrders,Total P4 Open WorkOrders
 30-Jun-16    1    0
 01-Jul-16    2    0
 02-Jul-16    2    1
 03-Jul-16    2    1
 04-Jul-16    2    1
 05-Jul-16    2    1
 06-Jul-16    2    1
 07-Jul-16    2    1
 08-Jul-16    2    0
```

Comment: First you need a calendar / tally table. This is a table (or view or whatever) that has a record for every day you're interested. Have a think about that, and also please add an appropriate database tag (do you actually mean SQLServer?)

Comment: Also please indicate whether you have the option of creating database objects (i.e. the calendar/tally table) or not.

Comment: it is SQL Server. I only have read access to the database.

Comment: thank you for the hint.. trying your idea on MS-Access with a calendar table.

Comment: I will add the SQL Server tag. Do you know what version?

Comment: You basically join your tally/calendar table `BETWEEN` the work order active dates and that tells you how many were active (open) on that day. You'll also need to transform your two tables into a from/to date basis (which you can also do on the fly)

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server 2014 - 12.0.4213.0 (X64)

Comment: I tried what you said with the calendar table.. but no idea on how to get the output like the way I mentioned.. I am not very keen with SQL or access. Please give me some more hints so that I can put some effort to it... thanks.

Comment: This is what I have so far .... (MS-Access)

TRANSFORM Count(workorder.wonum) AS CountOfwonum
SELECT cal.tdate
FROM cal, wostatus INNER JOIN workorder ON wostatus.wonum = workorder.wonum
WHERE (((wostatus.status) Not In ('Close','Complete')))
GROUP BY cal.tdate, wostatus.status
PIVOT workorder.priority;

Comment: I suggest you drop access and work on SQL Server. Are you allowed to connect and run queries in the database? It's going to be quite tricky to do 'inline' (without work tables) but we can try

Comment: I can run queries on the SQL server , but only read access, wont be able to create a cal table as you advised. thats an issue.. I've requested someone to create the cal table on the SQL server..

Answer (score 0):

We'll have to do this in pieces, I can't suggest a full answer until I know certain bits work. It's a shame (and unexpected) that there is no close date on the work order table.

First thing is to get a list of work orders with their open and close dates. Try this query and see if it works

```
-- Query 1: Get a list of work order with open and close dates
-- excluding WO's that were already closed before 1 Jan 2016

SELECT 
WO.WONum, 
WO.OpenDate, 
ISNULL(
    WC.CloseDate,
    CONVERT(DATE,'20990101',112)
) as CloseDate
FROM WorKOrder WO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT WONum, MAX(ChangeDate) as CloseDate
FROM WorKOrder
WHERE Status IN ('Close','Complete')
GROUP BY WONum
) WC
ON WO.WONum = WC.WONum
-- Exclude altogether any work orders that were closed prior to 1 Jan 2016
-- As these should not appear in the report
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM WorKOrder WAC
    WHERE Status IN ('Close','Complete')
    AND ChangeDate <= CONVERT(DATE,'20160101',112)
    AND WAC.WONum = WO.WONum
)
```

I assume `WONum` is unique on table `WorkOrder`? This query should list all work orders with their open and close dates. If the work order is still currently open we use a close date of 1st Jan 2099

The second query gives us all the dates we need to report against. Again run and ensure this works. Also please clarify how many days are we reporting on here? One year? ten?

Adapted from http://blog.waynesheffield.com/wayne/code-library/virtual-tally-numbers-table/

```
-- Query 2: Tally/calendar table
;WITH
TENS (N)      AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0),
THOUSANDS (N) AS (SELECT 1
                    FROM TENS t1
                         CROSS JOIN TENS t2
                         CROSS JOIN TENS t3),
TALLY (N)     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
                    FROM THOUSANDS)
SELECT TOP 1000 DATEADD(d,N,CONVERT(DATE,'20151231',112)) ADate
FROM TALLY;
```

Lets get these two queries working first and we'll go from there.

The final query sticks these two together. This still isn't finished but give you a list of dates, and how many work orders were still open on that date. Please try this. If it doesn't work we'll debug it. If it does work, you must test the numbers you're getting. Then we will add the P breakup

```
-- Query 3: stick it all together
;WITH
TENS (N)      AS (SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0 UNION ALL
                  SELECT 0 UNION ALL SELECT 0),
THOUSANDS (N) AS (SELECT 1
                    FROM TENS t1
                         CROSS JOIN TENS t2
                         CROSS JOIN TENS t3),
TALLY (N)     AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
                    FROM THOUSANDS)

SELECT 
WO.Priority,
CAL.D As IsOpenDate,
COUNT(*)
FROM WorKOrder WO
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
(
SELECT WONum, MAX(ChangeDate) as CloseDate
FROM WorKOrder
WHERE Status IN ('Close','Complete')
GROUP BY WONum
) WC
ON WO.WONum = WC.WONum
INNER JOIN 
(SELECT DATEADD(d,N,CONVERT(DATE,'20160101',112)) D FROM TALLY) CAL
ON CAL.D BETWEEN WO.OpenDate 
   AND   ISNULL(
            WC.CloseDate,
            CONVERT(DATE,'20990101',112)
         )
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM WorKOrder WAC
    WHERE Status IN ('Close','Complete')
    AND ChangeDate <= CONVERT(DATE,'20160101',112)
    AND WAC.WONum = WO.WONum
)
GROUP BY CAL.D, WO.Priority
```

Just confirming what this does: a figure of 1,000 against P4 and a date of 27-08-2016 means that on this date, there were 1,000 work orders at P4 that were opened *prior to* or *on* 27-08-2016, and not yet closed. So this is a count of how many work orders were open on that day. It's not a count of how many were open**ed** on the day. You shouldn't add this number up, you should use this in a non-additive trend graph

If you want to see the 1,000 individual work orders that make up this number you use query 1 and you add this to the end:

```
AND CONVERT(DATE,'20160827',112) BETWEEN WO.OpenDate 
       AND   ISNULL(
                WC.CloseDate,
                CONVERT(DATE,'20990101',112)
             )
```

Comment: The first query gives me an error, the second query works without any error. 

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 6
Incorrect syntax near '20990101'.
Msg 105, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Unclosed quotation mark after the character string ')
GROUP BY WONum
) WC
ON WO.WONum = WC.WONum

the seoncd one works.
'.

Comment: So I fixed the first query, and the second query is your tally table (created on the fly - no need to create any objects)

Comment: the first query worked after you fixed it.. listed a lot of records though... 12538210 records.. 
------------
date range is 01-Jan-2016 till-date ; hope I will be able to change the date range if there is a need...

Comment: How many work orders do you expect? (so far this is every work order listed out) What does `SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT WONum) FROM WorkOrder` return? Remember this isn't the final solution we're just setting it up. So we only need 1000 or so date records. I will update the answer.

Comment: Are there any work order closed prior to 01-Jan-2016 and if so do you want to exclude them altogether?

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*), COUNT(DISTINCT WONum) FROM WorkOrder = 12538210.

Yes, there are so many workorders closed before 1jan2016 and after too..we can exclude them if its going to speed up the execution of the query..

Comment: That query returns two numbers. You only posted one. I guess they numbers were the same (which tells me work orders are unique in the table). I will edit my answer further. Please try it

Comment: After running the third query, I get an error..  please see below. 


Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Type TALLY.date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 28
Type TALLY.date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 41
Type TALLY.date is not a defined system type.
Msg 243, Level 16, State 1, Line 16
Type TALLY.date is not a defined system type.

Comment: the query is working... time to execute : 19mins...
------------------------------------------------
sample output..; 
future dates show 521056 as the count.. 
------------------------------------------------
the rest of the dates shows different.. please see below..
IsOpenDate Count
27-09-2018 521056
.........
05-08-2016 521056
04-08-2016 522785
03-08-2016 536461
02-08-2016 552792
01-08-2016 563018
31-07-2016 595577
30-07-2016 604900
29-07-2016 609541

Comment: Excellent. There are various ways to reduce that run time but they require you to create things in the database (a tally table and indexes). I have edited again to group by priority. Please test